# Sequelize js: update / save in model's method

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

How to update a record inside model's method like 'node orm-2' In 'Sequelize'

In orm-2, Just use **this.save()**

```
var users = db.define('users',
    {
        id          : { type: 'serial', key: true },
        username    : { type: 'text', size: 25, unique: true, required: true },
        balance     : { type: 'integer', defaultValue: 0 },
    }, {
        timestamp: true,
        methods: {
            addBalance: function (howMany) {
                howMany = Math.abs(howMany);
                this.balance += howMany;
                this.save(function (err) {
                    console.log("added money to "+this.username+" : "+howMany);
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

But in Sequelize, I don't know yet

```
var wallet = sequelize.define('wallet', {
    balance : { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, defaultValue: 0, validate: { min: 0 } }
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    classMethods: {
        addBalance: function (howMany) {
            howMany = Math.abs(howMany);
            this.balance += howMany;
            //UPDATE Or SAVE HERE...
        }
    }
});
```

Is it have simple command or prefer another methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the `addBalance` method inside `instanceMethods`, not in `classMethods`, because you want to operate on a single instance of specified model

```
instanceMethods: {
    addBalance: function(howMany) {
        howMany = Math.abs(howMany);
        return this.set('balance', this.get('balance') + howMany).save();
    }
}
```

This method would return `Promise` resolving to current instance of model.

**EDIT**

Even better solution would be to use `instance.increment` method

```
addBalance: function(howMany) {
    howMany = Math.abs(howMany);
    return this.increment('balance', { by: howMany });
}
```

It would return the same as the option above.